# Excel Question: Cell A2=F2 , A8=F3 how can I achieve this?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to fill the column C = F data as long as the A counter is not restarting. I tried many things but it automatically update the and the F counter +1 in the subsequent cells.

I tried this
`=IF(A2<>-1;F2;F2+1)` but it keeps incrementing F cells I dont want it to increment the F cell just the A but I dont know how to achieve this

```
id  word    pred    label       
0   The              O    8001  Message-Topic
1   most             O    8002  Product-Producer
2   common           O    8003  Instrument-Agency
3   <e1>audits</e1>  A0-B 8004  Entity-Destination
4   were             O    8005  Cause-Effect
5   about            O    8006  Component-Whole
6   <e2>waste</e2>.  A1-B 8007  Product-Producer
7   and              O    8008  Member-Collection
8   recycling.       O    8009  Component-Whole
-1                   O    8010  Message-Topic
0   The              O    8011  Entity-Destination
1   <e1>company</e1>A0-B  8012  Other
2   fabricates       O    8013  Entity-Destination
3   plastic          O    8014  Product-Producer
4   <e2>chairs</e2>.A1-B  8015  Entity-Origin
-1                   O    8016  Entity-Origin
0   The              O    8017  Entity-Destination
1   school           O    8018  Other
2   <e1>master</e1>. A0-B 8019  Member-Collection
3   teaches          O    8020  Product-Producer
4   the              O    8021  Message-Topic
5   lesson           O    8022  Content-Container
6   with             O    8023  Product-Producer
7   a                O    8024  Other
8   <e2>stick</e2>. A1-B  8025  Entity-Origin
```

I want the Pred column starting c2=F2 as long as its the first sentence (till C11 or C10 I don't care about the -1 line)
then in the second sentence I want starting C12 till C16 = F3 and so on

Below is an image of my desired output
[image: Desired Output]

Comment: INDIRECT function should help you

Comment: can you elaborate more as I am not sure how INDIRECT function will help me

Comment: Show an example of the expected output and I’ll confirm my comment.

Comment: Done added an image of the desired output in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I follow what you want I edited it to this:

```
=IF(A2<0,"",IF(SIGN(A2)>=0,OFFSET(F$2,COUNTIF(A$2:A2,-1),)))
```

Then just dragged down.
See:

[image]

Comment: but the thing is I want from C2 to C10=Message-topic (F2)
from C12 to C16= Product Producer (F3)
from C18 to C26 = Instrument Agency (F4) and so on

Thanks though

Comment: I added an image of my desired output

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question correctly, but you can lock a cell-reference by using the dollar symbol. E.g.

```
=IF(A2<>-1;$F$2;F2+1)
```

You can choose to lock the row, column, or both depending on where you place the $.
Hope this helps.

Comment: sadly no, it didn't work I want 
=IF(A2<>-1;$F$2;F2+1) but the middle condition (the True condition) I dont want it to be F2 forever I want it to be F3 later when the counter restarts

but when I used your if condition it made them all message-Topic (f2)

so the first sentence starting from C2= message-topic till the end then 2nd sentence is Product-Producer till the end .when is the end when the cell after it is -1